# What research has examined the cost in time and money of conference attendance?

Tags: conference, reference-request

I am looking for surveys/studies that quantify the time and money academics spent on conferences/symposia/workshops/etc by both organizers and attendees. Specifically, I'm interested in both academic and institutional costs related to conference, travelling, and administrative tasks related to travel. (In my experience the overwhelming majority of expenses are covered by employer/grant/etc anyways.)

I am most interested in the field of computer science, and academics affiliated to US institutions.

Comment: Please clarify who spent the time and money? Organizers or attendees? And also the field?

Comment: @scaaahu I am interested in both.

Comment: @scaaahu I am also interested in comparing different fields but I specified one in the question. Basically my interest is in assessing time and money spent on conferences in academia, but circumventing to one field and one country is already a good start.

Comment: You might want to search around for the budgets for particular conferences which sometimes give you a breakdown of number of attendees, country, and other information you might find useful from past years.

Comment: What counts as time spent on a conference?  Presumably you include time spent attending the conference or travelling.  What about reviewing papers?  Preparing slides?  Writing the papers?

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician Conference, travelling, and administrative tasks related to travel.

Comment: By "money academics spent on conferences", do you mean money those academics spent personally, or money that was spent by their employer, or both?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Both but I have mostly interested by money that was spent by their employer. In my experience most (> 90%) expenses are covered by employer/grant/etc.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I've added your clarifications to the body of the question.

Answer (score 7):

I published a paper:
 Anderson, L., & Anderson, T. (2009). [Online professional development conferences: An effective, economical and eco-friendly option](http://www.cjlt.ca/index.php/cjlt/article/viewArticle/521/254.)  Canadian Journal of Learning  Technology, 35(2).

in which we calculated the costs (transportation, hotels, meals etc.) in dollars and in Carbon costs using a medium sized conference in the UK.
We were interested in showing the HUGE cost and carbon savings if the conference was held online and used this data in our book on Virtual Conferences.